# Two way replication of data between two PostgreSQL 13.1 schemas

Tags: django, postgresql, database-replication

All,
I have a Django multitenant application with PostgreSQL (13.1) as a backend. I’m in a situation where I need to replicate the data between “table 1” and “table 2”. Right now, I’m using logical replication (publish-subscribe) for this one-directional replication. But, we need to replicate the data in two ways (ie. From A  B and BA).
I have some questions for the experts while learning more about this situation. This would help me in finding a solution

**Context**

1. We have a user with permission in both schemas
2. Uses logical replication (Publish subscribe)
3. Logical replication from table 1 to Table 2 is working fine
4. But need to replicate data in both directions (ie. From A  B and BA)
5. Simultaneous data medication won’t happen in (in schema 1 or Schema 2)

[image]

**Questions**

1. Will this result in an infinite loop?
2. Is there any way to avoid this looping?